# C#: Map API results to Class Properties

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

I'm trying to build a program in which I consume an API through a client that a company has made available for its software.

Here's a [link](https://github.com/StarRez/StarRezApiClient) to it.

Though it does make it easier for one to establish a connection and make a call through its embedded methods, I'm having a difficult time manipulating the data once I receive it.

[Note: I know it's sort of meaningless to provide y'all with the background of the client and how I'm making the call, but I would think it'd be hard for one to get a glimpse of what's going on if I'm not even providing how the connection is happening behind the client or how the database looks.]

Previously, I tried manipulating the data directly after making the call like this (link below), but I realized this is too difficult for me since I'm still a noob at C#, and it's been hard to mess with the results (object) as a dynamic[] value.

[Link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TdNAA9)

Therefore, I believe it'd be best if I pursue the route of getting the data as an object, serialize it, turn it to (json), and map it to properties. I believe once I do this it should be easier to manipulate the data because I'd have an easier time turning the data into single values, lists, etc. However, I'm having a difficult time connecting the dots at this point of the code.

This is what I have so far..

I'm only interested in the EntryID, NameFirst, and NameLast of the results, but further along the way I do see myself utilizing the info from the other fields of this table and others. If someone could help me make the connection from the results to these properties, I would very much appreciate it. This would be a huge step in the application I'm trying to build using this API data.

Thanks in advance!

Class of Properties [Link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yq45jU)

JsonData Processor  [Link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ag1hsn)

JSON Results from Call [Link](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cbfb31d2)

```
 using System;
 using [Custom]Api;
 using Newtonsoft.Json;


 namespace testing2
  {
    public class Program
    {       
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        [CustomApi]Client connection = new [CustomApi]Client("BaseURL", 
       "Username", "Password");

        var value = 
     connection.Select("Entry",Criteria.Equals("NameLast","Rincon Recio"));

        string results = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);

        ///not sure if making results as string is the right call to begin 
         this
        //[Syntax where I tell results to match properties of Class 1]
        //[Create list of EntryID, NameFirst, NameLast]
        //[Display list in listbox]


        Console.WriteLine(results);

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Since you're receiving a JSON, you just need to deserialize it. It's an array of objects, so you could deserialize it to a `List<object>`, but also to a `Dictionary<string, string>[]` (and other types of collections). If you setup your classes, it's even easier to handle. You can use an online service to map the JSON to c# classes. There are many. Since your JSON is quite simple, you can also use Visual Studio `Paste special -> Paste JSON as classes` tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value)` shouldn't make a difference.

Try Deserialising `values` to array of `Class1`.
Like so

```cs
var realResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1[]>(values);
```

[Source](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm)

Comment: Terle, thank you. This worked. Not sure if I'll get in trouble for asking this, but I'm essentially trying to populate a listbox with these results. I've been able to accomplish this by using a for each loop. Now, what I'm having a hard time doing right now is telling the compiler to bind the selectedpathvalue to the entryid. I'm stuck doing that. My question is if the route I'm going with all of this is the right one?  I was not able to do a for each loop for the array unto the selected path value.

Comment: @ChunkyFresh, no no :), it's fine. I think I need to see some code? I assume you're doing WPF??

Comment: Hey Terle, I had to repost through a new post. This would've gone long if I would've continued this conversation without providing what's on my new post.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57193508/c-binding-listbox-items-to-property-of-api-call