# C#: Binding ListBox Items to property of API Call

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm building an application in which I run the following code to display the results in a listbox from an API call. Link below directs to full extent of script that runs app.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/gFL2M0

I am able to get the results from the API call, match them to Class1 properties, and display them in the listbox.

Nevertheless, I want to bind the EntryID property results to the values displayed in the listbox because once the user presses the button upon a selected value, I'm looking to get that value to run another command of another method or within the button's method itself.

This is where I'm here asking y'all for help (binding the API's parsed EntryID results to the selected values (displayed members)) of the listbox.

Two things:

1. The route I pursued to call and parse the API data is one I chose based on my current knowledge of C#. I apologize if this method is making this much more difficult. I'm still new to C#.
2. If you take a look at the link above, I will eventually make the API call a class of its own. I just went ahead and provided it twice in the script for context reasons.

Here's the code at the part of the button. Thank you in advance for the help!

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        StarRezApiClient call2 = new StarRezApiClient("BaseURL", "UserName", "Password");

        var selection = call2.Select("Entry", Criteria.Equals("NameLast", "Rincon Recio"));

        var transfer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selection);

        var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1[]>(transfer);

        foreach (var id in output)
        {

            testListBox.SelectedItem.Equals(id.EntryID);

            ///Assigns SelectedItem of ListBox to EntryID [WHERE I NEED HELP PLEASE] 
        }

        //TODO
        //MessageBox.Show(SelectedValue.ToString()); for testing

        //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("BaseURL?EntryID=" + SelectedItem); takes user to webpage of api results 

         }
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/yq45jU --- Class Properties

https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cbfb31d2 --- Json Results

Comment: Is `output` an array with a single element? If not, do you want to set multiple elements as selected?

Comment: @NicoSchertler Nico, thanks for replying. In this case, it is not. I have editted my post with a link to sample json results this call (query) retrieves. 5 results return after I make this call, and I'd appreciate the help in telling the listbox to make the EntryID the pathvalue after clicking either a button or the selected item itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

You want to add instances of `Class1` to your listbox, not just the text display. Which for proper display in a listbox wants the `.ToString()` method overridden.
Line 34 in your fiddle shows `testListBox.Items.Add(name.NameFirst + ' ' + name.NameLast);`

which should be `testListBox.Items.Add(name);`
The second part is making `Class1` whose code you did not include have a method like the following

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.NameFirst + ' ' + this.NameLast;
}
```

**Side note**

I use a wrapper access around listboxes or comboboxes like so for easier type-safe access.

I flesh out the interfaces as needed and fallback to direct access where strong doesn't necessarily make things any simpler.

```
  public class ListBoxT<T>
    {
        readonly ListBox _lb;
        public T SelectedItem { get => (T)_lb.SelectedItem; set => _lb.SelectedItem = value; }
        public void AddItem(T item) => _lb.Items.Add(item);
        public ListBoxT(ListBox lb) => this._lb = lb;

    }

    public class ComboBoxT<T>
    {
        readonly ComboBox _cb;

        public ComboBoxT(ComboBox cb) => this._cb = cb;

        public T SelectedItem { get => (T)_cb.SelectedItem; set => _cb.SelectedItem = value; }
        public Rectangle Bounds => this._cb.Bounds;
        public int Count => this._cb.Items.Count;
        public IReadOnlyCollection<T> Items { get => new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(_cb.Items.Cast<T>().ToList()); }
        public void BeginUpdate() => _cb.BeginUpdate();
        public void Clear() => _cb.Items.Clear();
        public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            _cb.SuspendLayout();
            _cb.Items.AddRange(items.Cast<object>().ToArray());
            _cb.ResumeLayout();
        }
        public void EndUpdate() => _cb.EndUpdate();
        public bool Enabled { get => _cb.Enabled; set => _cb.Enabled = value; }
        public int SelectedIndex { get => _cb.SelectedIndex; set => _cb.SelectedIndex = value; }
        public ComboBox Value => _cb;
        public T this[int x]
        {
            get => (T)this._cb.Items[x];
            set => this._cb.Items[x] = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is awesome, but I honestly can't make sense of this answer. It goes beyond my current understanding of C#. I guess if this is really the only way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do, then, I'm doomed. I'll need to get your answer and do research off of it.

Comment: edited for simplicity and clarity on actual answer vs. advanced for later ideas on how to handle this.

Comment: I appreciate everything you've posted, but this somewhat deviated from what I was primarily looking for which was binding the EntryID results to the selectedvaluepath of the selecteditem. I'll see if I can apply what you gave me to that goal.

Comment: `testListBox.SelectedValuePath = "EntryID";` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example. As Maslow noted, you should first add objects of `Class1` to your list, not plain strings. Then, you simply add the items that match your search criteria to the `SelectedItems` collection:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="list" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
class Class1
{
    public int EntryID { get; set; }

    public string NameFirst { get; set; }

    public string NameLast { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return NameFirst;
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        list.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Multiple;

        //fill list with dummy items
        var items = new Class1[10];
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            items[i] = new Class1() { EntryID = i, NameFirst = ((char)('A' + (char)i)).ToString() };
        list.ItemsSource = items;

        //simulate second API call
        var selection = new Class1[3];
        selection[0] = new Class1() { EntryID = 3 };
        selection[1] = new Class1() { EntryID = 4 };
        selection[2] = new Class1() { EntryID = 8 };

        list.SelectedItems.Clear();
        foreach (var sel in selection)
            foreach (var item in items.Where(i => i.EntryID == sel.EntryID))
                list.SelectedItems.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Instead of arrays, you might want to employ more flexible or more efficient data structures like `List<Class1>` or `Dictionary<int, Class1>`. I.e., when you get your result as an array, simply fill in these data structures from it. If you have a dictionary, you can directly get the element with a specific key instead of using the LINQ query (`.Where(...)`).

Btw, please do not use .Net Fiddle to simply add more code to your question. The question should be self-contained and show all relevant code. .Net Fiddles can be used as supplementary material to link to a running example. However, linking to a non-compiling fiddle is just making your question harder to follow.

Comment: Ahhh.. I'm so split now. At this point, I'm not sure if it'd be wiser to pursue the list/dictionary route to accomplish this. I'm not far into the code at all so I could still change my approach. Would this approach be easier? I was having a hard time creating lists from the object. That's why I pursued this route.

Comment: If you have your array, you can simply call `.ToList()` or `.ToDictionary(...)` to create these data structures.

Comment: Hey Nico, I did pursue the route of creating a list out of my results. However, I was unable to implement your solution to my app. May I ask you to check this out? This will provide much more context. https://dotnetfiddle.net/CIIQm5#

Comment: Please help us to help you. Turn the fiddle into a self-containing application. Remove the dependency to the `StarRezApiClient` and instead create your own class that simulates the two relevant calls (that return the two JSON strings). Make it compilable and then we can go from there.